# Error handling PHP class

Tags: php, class, error-handling

I am trying to write an error handler class for php. I've tested that the object has been created but it doesn't seem to be handling errors.

I used the same code in a function in the index file initially and it worked fine, but I'd rather have a class. Why is this not handling errors?

```
class class_error
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // set to the user defined error handler
        set_error_handler($this->errorHandler());
    }

    public function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        //don't display error if no error number
        if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
            return;
        }

        //display errors according to the error number
        switch ($errno)
        {
            case E_USER_ERROR:
                echo "<b>ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
                echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
                echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
                echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
                exit(1);
                break;

            case E_USER_WARNING:
                echo "<b>WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
                break;

            case E_USER_NOTICE:
                echo "<b>NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
                break;

            default:
                echo "<b>UNKNOWN ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
                break;
        }

        //don't execute PHP internal error handler
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Comment: yep ill give u a tick in a few ticks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
set_error_handler(array($this, "errorHandler"));
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: If your PHP is up to date, use short array syntax: `set_error_handler([$this, 'errorHandler'])`.

Comment: Did not even know that this exists. Thanks for sharing